# Problem adding ppa's in Deepin OS 15.4

Tags: debian, command-line, apt, ppa

I am running Deepin OS 15.4, which is based on Debian unstable.

When I type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

I get:

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpeel0gwwr/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpeel0gwwr/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 531EE72F4C9D234C: public key "Launchpad webupd8" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

---

Extension:

After installing gnupg2 and running the other command, I get:

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpiyqhvqsc/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpiyqhvqsc/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 531EE72F4C9D234C: public key "Launchpad webupd8" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 474, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 432, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 430, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.ssh'
```

Extension:

Now after running the two mentioned commands it gives me the first error again.

Comment: @peterh we can't edit bounty messages. Just leave a comment clarifying what you meant to say.

Comment: @terdon O.k., sorry.

Comment: @peterh no need to apologize, you did nothing wrong. Typos happen to the best of us. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Looks like `gpg-agent` is not running. Try to run `gpg-agent --homedir /home/<your_user_name>/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon` and then retry those command that have failed.

Comment: @ddnomad when I run your command it tells me `gpg-agent --homedir /home/alex/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
gpg-agent[10904]: WARNING: "--use-standard-socket" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one`

Comment: @The_Encoder then it's not what is broken. Hmm..

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The following commands should import the key by hand:

```
sudo add-apt-key 531EE72F4C9D234C
```

Give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that maybe the problem is that Alin's key is not available... please take a look at [this](https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html) example and you'll see in the second image that the public key should be something like

> "Launchpad webupd8 for ...."

and yours only says "Launchpad webupd8"

Have you already tried the *Adding this PPA to your system* from [this](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8) link? if you have, then maybe you should contact [Alin Andrei](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard) and report the issue.